# Onion skin wont show unless I draw on the frame, and only shows the lines directly around it from previous frames and won't lower onion skin's opacity

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d

My goal is to animate 2d with an Onion skin working properly. I want to be able to draw the first keyframe, the 2nd keyframe one over, and then draw an in-between between those 2, being able to see both frames at a lower opacity in their entirety before and while I draw the inbetween. But, instead, when onion skin is enabled, when I go to draw the inbetween, I can't see the frames before or after until I draw a stroke, and then onion skin only activates to the strokes that are immediately around the stroke I drew in the inbetween. On top of that, it doesn't seem to be reading the opacity variable of .5, showing the onion skin as if it's a full 1? The onion skin custom colors don't seem to be working either. It's pure black instead of the colors I input, despite having the check enabled. After I draw the inbetween, and then revisit the frames before and after, It show's only activated parts of the inbetween, having the same issue.
Any advice or fixes around this is greatly appreciated.

[image: This is Keyframe 1]
[image: This is Keyframe 2]
[image: This is when I draw an Inbetween]

^Problematic, where's the rest of the before and after frames? How come I only see activated strokes? How come Onion skin's Opacity won't lower on before and after frames?

[image: This is when I go back to Keyframe 1 after I draw Inbetween]
[image: Custom Colors don't seem to be working, either]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing actual drawn lines with onion skin. Actual onion skin gets displayed with colors and transparency as programmed in the onon skin properties panel. Check if it's enabled in the overlays section, in the layers panel and in the onion skin panel.

Try appending the GPencil object into a new file, as this procedure can get rid of some rare bugs.

Try also to enable this function into a brand new file, to get familiar with its behaviour.

[image]